# Save the transformed document (the output of the xml/xsl transformation) in a html file on disc

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, xslt

I write code in visual basic (visual studio, Windows Forms Applications),  transforming an XML file through an XSL file using: ?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSL.xsl"?, and getting the desired output on windows default browser. I do not want to appear the output on the brower. My target is to write the correct vb-net code in order to **save** above output in an **html** file on disk.

Comment: Are you looking for the API documentation of `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`? If you have existing code in VB.NET and expect us to help adapt it then you should include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xsl-xslcompiledtransform-transform(system-string-system-string) is the straight-forward overload of the `Transform` method taking an input file and writing a result file